# Installing DNS Debian 7 in Virtualbox

Tags: debian, dns

I'm trying install dns on debian 7 ,and package 'bind9' has no installation candidate. how i fix it?

Comment: Why not a more recent version of Debian?

Comment: According to https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/bind9 it should be there. What are the contents of your sources.list?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to get more looks; this has nothing to do with Virtualbox.

Answer (score 3):

Which Debian repositories are configured in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Debian 7's long term support ended at the end of May 2018.
Before 2019-07-06, Debian 7 was still available on (some?) regular Debian repositories as "oldoldstable", as Debian 9 was the current stable release. But on that day, Debian 10 was released, and Debian 7 was moved to the [archives](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive).

You may need to update your repository configuration if you want to still stay with an obsolete release. Old BIND versions have known vulnerabilities, so I'd recommend updating to a supported release instead.